# Rosource myConverter not found

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2019

I have a view with this code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Recursos/Diccionarios/MyConvertersDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

The converter:

```
public class MyConverter: IValueConverter
    {
    //CODE
        
    }




    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


//I have this xalm file in the folder ../Recursos/diccionarios:


    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
        <conv:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

The error when I try to use the converter in the Datagrid column is that the resource MyConverter is not found.

If I right-click in the converter and go to definition, in the XAML dictionary, I get the error that I could not load the file or assembly MyApp version XXX culture=neutral. The system can't find the specified file.

But if I right-click in the XAML dictionary and go to definition, I go to the converter, in the MyConverter.cs file, where I have the implementation of the converter.

Also, I have realized that when I try to use the converter in the Datagrid column, the IntelliSense finds the converter, I have a list with all my converters, so it is found too by the IntelliSense.

So I don't understand why I get this error if when I go to the definition in each case, I finally arrive at the implementation of the converter, so it is found.

Comment: Does your project build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a relative path on your ResourceDictionary `Source`, try using a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). I suspect you are running into a runtime issue, where the relative path may be different when the binaries are built.

So for your case, it would look something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Recursos/Diccionarios/MyConvertersDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I use "Source="Pack://Application,,," I get the error that says error searching/finding the resource Pack://Application,,,/Recursos/Diccionarios/docResumenesComponnetesViewConverters.xaml.

Comment: Hi,@Álvaro García. What is the complete structure of your project? Are resources and classes in the same namespace? Is it possible to show a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, you might want to also change "Pack" and "Application" to "pack" and "application". Just in case WPF may be case sensitive with this syntax.  But I also agree with Hui Liu, your project structure might be different from our understanding because you have not shared it yet.  Please show it, so we can identify any issues.